# Select e-mails in Gmail using keyboard

Tags: gmail

One thing I find myself doing a lot is trying to navigate my e-mails using my keyboard.  I have found the "caret" showing current focused e-mail, in Compact dark theme, is a blue indicator and that can be moved up and down using the keyboard. You can also use Enter to read the currently selected e-mail.

What bothers me is that Spacebar isn't used to select the currently focused e-mail.  The Spacebar has more of a page down functionality. Nothing has annoyed me more than having to select a group of e-mails using my mousepad on my laptop; not to mention it is very inefficient to have to position the cursor precisely and hope you don't accidentally start dragging the item instead of selecting the check box.

**So my question is, how can I use my keyboard to select e-mails in Gmail -mail? **

Also, how I can delete the selected e-mails using my keyboard without using tab, if possible?

Comment: Have you enabled Keyboard Shortcuts via (in Gmail) Settings > General > Keyboard Shortcuts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to manually enable Shortcuts in Gmail by:

- Go to Settings > General > Keyboard Shortcuts and check 'Enable Keyboard Shortcuts'. Click Save

Now press <kbd>?</kbd> on your keyboard to see a list of shortcuts you can use, or go [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6594?hl=en&ctx=mail).

By default, press <kbd>o</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the 'conversation' or email.

To use <kbd>Space</kbd> as the key to open emails:

- Go to Settings > Labs > Custom Keyboard Shortcuts. Check enable.
- Go to Settings (again) > Keyboard Shortcuts (it will be a new tab, near to 'Labs').
- Go to 'Open conversation'. In the 'or' box, type in `\32` which is the [ASCII code](http://ascii.cl/) for space bar.

Now, you will be able to open emails with space bar (it worked for me!).

Comment: I guess this is part one.  What I think is happening is because I have a scroll bar on my page (using Google Chrome), when I hit Enter, Chrome is using that as page down functionality. Can you duplicate it this behavior too?

Comment: @NETscape Strange... It doesn't happen for me... I use Google Chrome as well.... Could you try a different browser if you have access to one? I think space does normally move the page down, but that's not happening to me. I don't know why...

Comment: So I wanted to use spacebar to "Select conversation" not "Open conversation".  Even when I don't have a scroll bar (only show 10 conversations at a time), and I use \32 for the "or" shortcut, hitting the spacebar doesn't select the convo :/. So I have: x "or" \32

Comment: @NETscape OK, I thought you wanted it for open. So you changed the `\32` to `Select Conversation`? And you've made sure you can't scroll down (by having 10 emails on the page)? But the spacebar doesn't work? Do I understand you correctly? I can't understand why not! It works for me

Comment: Well if it works for you, I'll leave it as the answer. Using a Win 8 laptop if that means anything.  I can deal with using the 'x' key

Comment: @NETscape Sorry about not being able to fix it, I'm using Win7 so it is possible that Win8 is the problem here - or I'm just special :). Sorry, again